# What happens when I define macros with the same name

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

What happens when I have multiple `#define`s with the same name in one sourcefile:

for example:

```
#define Dummy 1
#define Dummy 2
```

I do NOT intend to use it, but saw something similar in production code. Is this covered by the standard?

Comment: Note that you could try this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This would give me an answer for the specific (pre-)compiler I use, but might change if I use another one. Thats why I ask.

Comment: Then use a standard C compiler...

Comment: @Lundin Different compilers do different things, if the behaviour is implementation defined or undefined. If this would be one of those, an empiric test would have no value.

Comment: @KamiKaze Simply use the best conforming C compiler `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Now you'll get a compiler error if there are constraint violations.

Comment: @Lundin: Any C implementation, no matter how strictly it conforms to the standard, is only one element in the set of all possible conforming C implementations and can neither convey total information about the set nor be authoritative.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Compile the code as I describe. Did you get a diagnostic message? Then the compiler is conforming. If you run the program despite diagnostic messages, then the behavior is undefined. What's not clear to you?

Comment: @Lundin: “if the compiler conforms, then it gives a diagnostic message” does not imply “If the compiler gives a diagnostic message, then the C standard requires that it give a diagnostic message.” What is not clear to you?

Comment: @EricPostpischil You'll naturally have to know what the C standard says first. Which is covered by the accepted answer.

Comment: @Lundin: The fact that you have to know what the C standard says first means that your previous statement of “Then use a standard C compiler” is not useful. Using a standard C compiler does not answer the question of what the C standard says.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's constraint violation and as such, a conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.

[C11, 6.10.3 Macro replacement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p2) states:

> An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another #define preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. [..]

As noted, it's not a constraint violation if the replacement is identical. So

```
#define X 1
#define X 2
```

requires a diagnostic; whereas

```
#define X 1
#define X 1
```

is OK. Similar constraints apply for function-like macros (C11, 6.10.3, 2).

Comment: So it is not safe to say that the last one is active. It is more or less undefined?

Comment: Does violating a constraint lead to undefined behaviour? C standard doesn't explicitly say so. But in the absence of a *defined* behaviour, it's probably logical to conclude it's undefined.

Comment: @KamiKaze Yes, it is not safe to assume that. A constraint violation is the same thing as undefined behavior.

Comment: @P.P. Violating a constraint rather leads to "a violation of the C language", so it is worse yet. I know there's some text saying that if a "shall"/"shall not" outside constraints is violated, then there's UB. Meaning that if a constraint is violated, we have something worse than UB. I don't think the standard has a term for it, other than "must issue a diagnostic message".

Comment: @P.P.: If a source text violates a syntactic constraint, then it does not form a C program—it is not a text (a string of symbols) for which the C standard defines behavior.

Comment: `it's not a constraint violation if the replacement is identical` <== critical piece of information. I was accidentally defining the exact same macro in multiple places then found it and was wondering why no error was thrown!

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
#define Dummy 1
#define Dummy 2
```

is the same as:

```
#define Dummy 2
```

But you'll get probably (I'm not sure what the standard says) a warning such as `'Dummy': macro redefinition` for the second `#define`

In other words: the last `#define` wins.

If you want to do things properly, you should use `#undef`:

```
#define Dummy 1
#undef Dummy
#define Dummy 2    // no warning this time
```

BTW: there are scenarios where it is perfectly OK to change the definition of a macro.

Comment: and you don't get the warning if the value is the same for both `#define`

Comment: Redefining a macro without `undefine` it is technically invalid.

Comment: If it violates the C standard there is no point in reasoning about what will happen. A constraint violation is the same as undefined behavior. So the behavior "last define wins" that you describe in this question is by no means given and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @Lundin: In the same Q&A, you have both told us to use a conforming C compiler to discern the behavior asked about in the question and that the compiler behavior used to inform this answer is not indicative of the standard.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: we both lack of C-norm-fu :) this seems implementation defined. `gcc` users (dunno for `clang`) are okay with your answer. Maybe not Turbo-C ones :)

Answer (score 1):

An example from C Standards#6.10.3.5p8

> EXAMPLE 6 To demonstrate the redefinition rules, the following sequence is **valid**.
>
> ```
>       #define      OBJ_LIKE      (1-1)
>       #define      OBJ_LIKE      /* white space */ (1-1) /* other */
>       #define      FUNC_LIKE(a)   ( a )
>       #define      FUNC_LIKE( a )( /* note the white space */ \
>                                    a /* other stuff on this line
>                                        */ )
> ```
>
> But the following redefinitions are **invalid**:
>
> ```
>       #define      OBJ_LIKE    (0)     // different token sequence
>       #define      OBJ_LIKE    (1 - 1) // different white space
>       #define      FUNC_LIKE(b) ( a ) // different parameter usage
>       #define      FUNC_LIKE(b) ( b ) // different parameter spelling
> ```

[*emphasis mine*]

Hence, this

```
#define Dummy 1
#define Dummy 2
```

is not valid.